# How to make search of local data faster in iOS app?

Tags: ios, ipad, uitableview

I have a prepopulated Coredata file that I would like to search in iOS app. The file has indexed words like this ~ (70,000 lines) ~10 MB file.

```
ad
adam
arm
apple
..
..
zen
zener
```

I have built Coredata from the file and I query SQLLite For instance: Give me all the words that start with "a". It takes about 300 mseccs on simulator for search, but takes about 2 seconds or longer on the iPad device? How can I make this faster? How do other search engine type of apps do it on the device?

```
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//This will get list of words begining with letters from search word
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
-(void) FetchWords
{
NSString *entityName=@"KeyWord";
NSString *sortKey = @"word";
NSArray *fetchColumns = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"word", nil];

//init fetch request
NSFetchRequest *req = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];

NSString *query = self.searchBar.text;

//
//split search phrase into words - searches words with any order and not case senitive - remove last space if any
//
NSMutableArray *words = [[query componentsSeparatedByString:@" "] mutableCopy];
if([words[words.count-1] isEqualToString:@""])
    [words removeObjectAtIndex:[words count]-1];

if(query.length)
{

    NSMutableArray *subpredicates = [NSMutableArray array];

    if(words.count >1)
    {
       [self GetMatchingCategoryCodes];
      //  NSLog(@"%@",categories);


        for (NSString *code in categories)
        {
            //intersection between last word and previous categories already filtered for previous words in search

           NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"word BEGINSWITH[cd] %@ AND code BEGINSWITH [cd] %@",words[words.count-1],code]; 
           [subpredicates addObject:pred];
        }

      req.predicate = [NSCompoundPredicate orPredicateWithSubpredicates:subpredicates];

    }
    else
    {
       for(NSString *token in words)
       {
           NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"word BEGINSWITH[cd] %@",token];
          [subpredicates addObject:pred]; 
       }
       req.predicate = [NSCompoundPredicate orPredicateWithSubpredicates:subpredicates];

    }
}


//setup request
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:entityName inManagedObjectContext:context];
[req setEntity:entity];
[req setFetchBatchSize:100];

//sort descriptors
NSSortDescriptor *desc = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:sortKey ascending:YES];
NSArray *descriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:desc];
[req setSortDescriptors:descriptors];

//for unique values - ignore repeatition
req.propertiesToFetch = fetchColumns;
req.returnsDistinctResults = YES;
req.resultType = NSDictionaryResultType;


//execute request
NSError *error;
Codes = [context executeFetchRequest:req error:&error];

//  NSLog(@"Fetched=%d",Codes.count);

}
```

Comment: Show us the code that does the query.

Answer (score 0):

You could try Lazy Loading and limit the output to 50 or less items, as they will not be visible on the screen anyway. When the user scrolls in the results list you fetch more as needed.

Comment: Do I do this with [req setFetchBatchSize:TheNumber];?

Comment: req.fetchLimit = 50; req.fetchOffset = (according to position)

Answer (score 0):

If you display these words in a table view you certainly should consider using NSFetchedResultsController and enable caching.

Answer (score 0):

There are more than one optimization methods.

Using CONTAINS for example slows the search down. Apple recommends to use a separate entity for the search words - called searchWords (or whatever), and in that store all the words you are searching for, made lower case and with accents removed. These separate entities have a relationship linking them back to the original objects. Make sure the word field is indexed.

Further only the first letter typed into the search field should ever hit the disk. After the first letter you should only be refining the search results of what is already in memory.

You should filter that array that is in memory (from the first letter search) using the predicate you already have and avoid executing a fetch request as it is unnecessary.

In addition, if you are going to search on data that is already in memory (such as living in a NSFetchedResultsController) then your entire search should only hit the objects in memory. Going out to disk is unnecessary and terribly wasteful. If not using a ResultsController you could cache the data for yourself in an Array performing only searches in memory after your first hit. This should speed up your requests as well.

So using a FetchedResultsController with batch size and caching enabled should improve your search, too.

BTW: You could perform those "intense" searches on a background thread to avoid the keyboard from lagging. But you have to make sure to only execute one background request in a time and fetch only the latest results. Marking the threads at a lower priority ensures that the UI will perform well.

There is a wwdc about improving the speed of coredata searches with sample code here:
[Apple WWDC Core Data](http://developer.apple.com/itunes/?destination=adc.apple.com.4092349126.04109539109.4144345613?i=2041584141)
[Optimizing Core Data Performance on iPhone OS (Slides)](http://adcdownload.apple.com//wwdc_2010/wwdc_2010_video_assets__pdfs/137__optimizing_core_data_performance_on_iphone_os.pdf)
[Optimizing Core Data Performance on iPhone OS (Video)](https://developer.apple.com/itunes/?destination=adc.apple.com.4092349126.04109539109.4144345647?i=1251375466)

Comment: I use BEGINsWITH because that is what I need. The words are indexed. However, I have not tried reducing the fetch number, like @n0oitaf also suggested.

Comment: It was just an example, I do not know the exact performance of beginswith, but it might be slow as well due to disk searches and case sensivity - see my edits

Comment: Do you happen to know the name of the video?